# Is there a way to upload multiple .zip files within an [R] Shiny application and select a specific file type to extract?

Tags: r, shiny, zip

I am currently only able to deal with one .zip archive at a time even if I set "multiple=T":

```
ui.R {
...fileInput("zippers", "upload .zip files",multiple=T,accept = ".zip"),
}
```

I can retrieve the names of the files I'm interested in (found in another topic) for a single instance as well:

```
server.R{
zipped_csv_names <- grep('\\.csv$', unzip(input$zippers$datapath, list=TRUE)$Name, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE) 
}
```

if I try two or more files I get the "Error: invalid zip name argument"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a list of data.frames with the path to the zip file and the names of the csv files inside.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  v <- reactiveValues(zipped_csv_names = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$zippers, {
    csv_names <- lapply(input$zippers$datapath, function(x){
      z <- unzip(x, list = T)
      csvFile <- grep("*.csv", z$Name, value = T)
      if (length(csvFile) > 0)
        return(data.frame(fPath = rep(x, n = length(csvFile)), fName = csvFile))
    })
    v$zipped_csv_names <- csv_names[!sapply(csv_names, is.null)]
  })
}
```